# get values inside of input type text from a table with jquery

Tags: jquery, struts2, struts2-jquery

My question is following: how to get the value of the code shown below, I need get the value from `id="idMaquinaSalidaD<%=i%>"` but of all rows, I tried this

```
   var valoresMaquinas = $(".listaMaquinasSalidaD").val();
```

but don't work, and only give me the value of the firt row, somebody can figure it out this.

```
    <table>    
     <thead>
                <tr>

                    <th>Hora</th>
                    <th>Ruta</th>
                    <th>Maquina</th>


                </tr>
                </thead>

                <tbody>
                <%int i=10;%>
                <s:iterator value="datosPlan" var="datosPlanLoading" status="valorDatosPlan">

                    <%--//cambia de color la fila en la que se encuentra le cursor--%>
                    <tr id="<%=i%>"
                            <%
                                if(i%2 == 0)
                                {
                            %>
                        class="alt"
                        style="background: #E1EEf4;color: #00557F;"
                        onmouseover="destacarFila(this.id);"
                        onmouseout="colorOriginalFila(this.id,0);"
                            <%
                            }
                            else
                            {   %>
                        onmouseover="destacarFila(this.id);"
                        onmouseout="colorOriginalFila(this.id,1);"
                            <%
                                }
                                i++;
                            %>
                            >
                        <%--<input type="hidden" id="<%="editar"%>${listaHorariosLoading.codigoHorario}" value="${listaHorariosLoading.nombreHorario}">--%>

                         <td>
                            <p>
                                <s:property value="hora"/>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p>
                                <s:property value="ruta"/>
                            </p>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <p>
                               <%--<s:textfield type="text" name="maquina" style="width:100;"/>--%>
                                <%--<input type="text" id="idMaquinaSalidaD<%=i%>" name="maquinaSalidaD" value="${maquina}" onblur="$.publish('verificarCupo',[this]);"/>--%>
                                 <input type="text" id="idMaquinaSalidaD<%=i%>" class="listaMaquinasSalidaD" name="maquinaSalidaD" value="${maquina}" onblur="$.publish('verificarCupo',[this]);"/>
                            </p>
                        </td>

                    </tr>

                </s:iterator>
                <%--voy sumando las maquinas ingresadas para pasarlas en una sola variable--%>
                <input type="hidden" id="listaMaquinaIngresadas" name="listaMaquinasIngresadas" value=""/>
                </tbody>

  </table>
```

Comment: It may be helpful for the purposes of answering this question, for you to provide the HTML as seen by your browser. Server-side code in a question like this is not very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
    var valoresMaquinas = $('.listaMaquinasSalidaD');
    for (var i = 0; i < valoresMaquinas .length; i++) {
        console.log($(valoresMaquinas [i]).val());
    }
```

Basically, your valoresMaquinas variable is an array of your elements having the class listaMaquinasSalidaD. When you execute the val() method on that array, it will return the value of the first element.

However, if you iterate through the array, you can access the values of the individual elements. Does that help?

Comment: Ok, I going to try thus and I'll tell you later

Answer (score 1):

This will give you an array of all the values:

```
 var valoresMaquinas = $("[id^='idMaquinaSalidaD']").map(function(i,v) {
     return v.value;
 }).get();
```

Comment: hey, that code is work fine but you can explain me or tell me what read to understand.

Comment: The [**.map() | jQuery API Documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/map/) would be a great place to start. Give it a try.